# What is the purpose of SPARK_ENV_LOADED environment variable?

Tags: apache-spark

I am using the Spark hidden rest api to submit spark applications as [described here.](http://arturmkrtchyan.com/apache-spark-hidden-rest-api) When I submit the `CreateSubmissionRequest` JSON without the following

```
"environmentVariables" : {
    "SPARK_ENV_LOADED" : "1"
},
```

the job fails with the following ERROR

```
WARN Worker: Driver driver-20170206152610-0010 failed with unrecoverable exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

What is the purpose of SPARK_ENV_LOADED property?

Comment: It's neither a Spark *property*, nor a Java *system property*, but an OS *environment variable*... AFAIK it's simply used in one of the scripts used for command-line execution (i.e. `load-spark-env.sh` on Linux and `load-spark-env.cmd` on Windows) to make sure that `spark-env.*` is only executed once. You can give it any value, the script only checks whether it's empty or not.

Comment: From your error message it appears that in the app running the REST API, there is a call to `System.getenv("SPARK_ENV_LOADED")` without any thought about the fact that `getenv` may return Null. Ahem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SPARK_ENV_LOADED environment variable tells you that the Apache Spark environment has been loaded. It lets you check to make sure that the environment is loaded, and only loaded once.  See https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-submit.html